# How do I bring instance attributes into a @staticmethod

Tags: python, oop, descriptor

I have a base class, like so:

```
class coordinates(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self.y = y

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, z):
        self.z = z
```

Then I create a child class that will inherit from coordinates, and have a static method in it, that will use instance attributes like x, y, and z ... like so:

```
class volume(coordinates):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)
        self.volume = self.calculate_volume()

    def calculate_volume(self):
        return self.x * self.y * self.z

    @staticmethod
    def goes_through(x, y, z, h, l):
        if x < l and y < h:
            return f"Use surface {x}{y} to go through"
        elif y < l and x < h:
            return f"Use surface {y}{x} to go through"
        elif x < l and z < h:
            return f"Use surface {x}{z} to go through"
        elif z < l and x < h:
            return f"Use surface {z}{x} to go through"
        elif z < l and y < h:
            return f"Use surface {z}{y} to go through"
        elif y < l and z < h:
            return f"Use surface {y}{z} to go through"
        else:
            return "Object can't go through"
```

Then I instantiate an object and attempt to get it's volume and see if it goes through and how:

```
obj1 = volume(100, 200, 400)
print(obj1.volume)
print(obj1.goes_through(obj1.x, obj1.y, obj1.z, 200, 350))
```

But I get this error instead:

> [Previous line repeated 993 more times] RecursionError: maximum
> recursion depth exceeded

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Property Def's are wrong. Please try with right definitions. It will work. https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/property.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your getters and setters are calling themselves. When you do `self.x = x` in your constructor, this calls your x setter. Then in your x setter, you also do `self.x = x`. This calls your x setter again. That again calls your x setter, and so on and so on until you run out of space on the stack and Python raises a RecursionError.

You can get rid of all your setters and getters, and your code will work just fine.

```
class coordinates(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Alternatively, you could use different attribute names to store the data in your getters and setters, so that they don't call themselves.

```
class coordinates(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self._y = y

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, z):
        self._z = z
```

However, if you have no special reason to do something like this, it is simpler to not use getters and setters in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Proper setter/getter set up is:

```
class Obj(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value
```

You do no need to do that however. In your case the `__init__` function is sufficient.

Comment: thank you @sarartur for taking the time to answer and share a valid example. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

hope it will work without using getter or setter.

```
class coordinates(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class volume(coordinates):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)
        self.volume = self.calculate_volume()

    def calculate_volume(self):
        return self.x * self.y * self.z

    @staticmethod
    def goes_through(x, y, z, h, l):
        if x < l and y < h:
            return f"Use surface {x}{y} to go through"
        elif y < l and x < h:
            return f"Use surface {y}{x} to go through"
        elif x < l and z < h:
            return f"Use surface {x}{z} to go through"
        elif z < l and x < h:
            return f"Use surface {z}{x} to go through"
        elif z < l and y < h:
            return f"Use surface {z}{y} to go through"
        elif y < l and z < h:
            return f"Use surface {y}{z} to go through"
        else:
            return "Object can't go through"


obj1 = volume(100, 200, 400)
print(obj1.volume)
print(obj1.goes_through(obj1.x, obj1.y, obj1.z, 200, 350))
```